# How do I get instance of Webbrowser inside currently active tab in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a tab control with three tabs each having a web browser inside the tab. ( Tab has other controls too inside it ).

I want to get the instance of the web browser inside the currently active tab.

How do I get it?

Comment: what does controls return? I need an instance of web browser

Comment: could you provide a code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a TabControl named "TabControl1", this should do the trick:

```
public Control GetWebBrowserControl()
{
    foreach (Control ctl in TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls) {
        if (ctl is WebBrowser) {
            return ctl;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```